# How to call a javascript function on selecting a field in odoo

Tags: javascript, odoo-8

Currently i am developing a module in odoo. I have a field. what i want is when i select the field. I need to execute a java script function. How can i do that?

My field:

```
roomType = fields.Selection([('meeting','Meeting Room'),('discussion','Discussion Room')],required=True)
```